# Button group with one radio and many checkboxes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Are there any sites or documents that include the ability for a bootstrap button group that works as a checkbox other than the first button which works as a radio. So one or many essentially.

I've scoured around for a while and did create a custom group in jQuery but was way too easy to break which probably prompted inefficient code.

This is essentially what I'm looking for. Only the first, or the rest but not both?

[image: This would be all]

[image]

Apologies if I've dropped the ball on this and it's something simple!

Comment: did you look at https://mdbootstrap.com/components/bootstrap-checkbox/#classicbuttons ?

Comment: Unfortunately I did! @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: Then how is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: The default Bootstrap implementation supports mixed input types, it would just be on you to write the JavaScript listener to detect "All" being clicked and take the appropriate actions. Have you tried that?